# React native - add discovered ble devices to set, and add option to picker

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, set

I am using a Picker in react native. While the screen is open, the device scans for ble devices, and adds them to a `devices` array in the state. The picker should have an option for each of the values in the `devices` array.

Ordinarily, I would do this:

Constructor:

```
this.state = { devices: [] };
```

When a device is found:

```
let devices = this.state.devices;
devices.push(device.id);
this.setState({ devices: devices });
```

And then do the Picker like this:

```
<Picker>
  {(this.state.devices).map((item, index) => {
    return <Picker.item key={index} label={item} value={item} />;
  })}
</Picker>
```

This works fine, except that since devices are constantly re-discovered, they end up the array multiple times. Not only is this useless, but the array length grows until the app runs out of memory.

To fix this, I tried using a set, since that should automatically not contain duplicates:

Constructor:

```
this.state = { devices: new Set() };
```

When a device is found:

```
let devices = this.state.devices;
devices.add(device.id);
this.setState({ devices: devices });
```

Picker:

Since the set does not have a map function, I took the entries (an iterator), and turned it into an array, and then mapped it:

```
<Picker>
  {Array.from(this.state.devices.entries).map((item, index) => {
    return <Picker.item key={index} label={item} value={item} />;
  })}
</Picker>
```

This, does not work. The debug tools suggest that the set in the state never gets added to, so I think that's the problem (rather than with the picker), but I don't understand why that would be the case.

No errors are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check first and then push in your array to avoid duplicate entries,

```
let devices = this.state.devices;
if(devices.indexOf(device.id) == -1){
  devices.push(device.id);
  this.setState({ devices: devices });
}
```

This will surely not push deviceID that is already in state.